# Low water pressure in one part of the house

Tags: water-pressure

The house that we are renting has decent water pressure inside and out the house, except for the en-suite bathroom to the main bedroom.

From what it looks to me, I think that the en-suite was an add on at a later stage to the house.

The water pressure is very low from all taps/shower/toilet in the en-suite.

Any idea as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: It's possible that there's a valve somewhere that's only half open, or the plumbing is clogged up galvanized pipe. There's no way for anybody here to know that, since you've told us absolutely nothing about the plumbing. What size and type of pipe is used to supply the bathroom? Where does the supply for the bathroom tap off of the plumbing, and what size/material is the pipe that the supply taps into? Are there any valves where the supply for the bathroom splits off, and if so what type of valve (and is it fully open)? Is the problem with both hot and cold?

Comment: Is there a water heater dedicated to this area, or does the supply come from a central location? Have you actually measured the pressure, or does it just *seem* like less?  Are there low flow fixtures installed in the bathroom?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about the plumbing, and simply going by the fact that you said the bathroom was an add on. I'd have to guess that there are low flow fixtures installed, which are restricting the flow.